# Can I use CommonJS Module System in a typescript Project?

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, commonjs

I have a new project and I want to code using **Visual Studio**, **Typescript**, **ASP.net Core** and **CommonJS Module System**. Actually I need a Module System to organize my dependencies. What should I do?

Can I use **CommonJS Module System** in a typescript Project using Visual Studio?

ts config:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use it in a same manner that you would use it in Javascript. 
Typescript is superset of Javascript, all things possible in Javascript are also possible in Typescript.

Refer to this:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

And search (ctrl/cmd + f) for 'require'